# All actions in test are fired twice when async is used in beforeEach

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm writing `E2E` tests for `Angular` app, However all actions called in tests are fired twice.

I have tried removing any custom commands I previously used.

```
describe('some tests', () => {
beforeEach(async() => {
    const data = {
        'data':'someData'
    }
    cy.visit('url');
    const window = await cy.window();
    window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*');
})

it('test1', () => {
    cy.get('#login-field').type('email', {force: true});
    cy.get('#password-field').type('password', {force: true});
    cy.get('#login-button').click({force: true});
})
```

})

`{force: true}` is used because otherwise Cypress reports them as not visible due to `overflow: hidden` in one of parents.

I expect every action to be fired once, but they are fired twice and performed at same time, e.g. type 'email' fires twice and 'eemmaaiill' is typed in field instead of 'email'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will wonder: this is issue with Cypress, if we use `async` in `beforeEach` then action in test will be performed twice. Current solution is to don't use `async` or move code that uses it to test iteself.